# Get paramaters name from external function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get parameter name from external function.
Example:

```
    function get_direction(value, site){
       //return "left", "right", "up" or"down"
    }

    $("#item").animate({ get_direction(1,2) : 1000 });
```

and I want execute something like:

```
$("#item").animate({ left : 1000 });
```

Comment: you can retunr from function object what you need, or use anonymous function for that

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this:

```
function get_direction(value, site){
  //return "left", "right", "up" or"down"
}

var opts = {};

opts[get_direction(1,2)] = 1000;

$("#item").animate(opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
function get_direction(value, site){
   //return "left", "right", "up" or"down"
}

var obj = {};
obj[get_direction(1,2)] = 1000;

$("#item").animate(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want, in the way you've written it, is impossible. You'll want to instead use a wrapper around the animate, and then use that.

```
function animateObject(item, direction, value) {
    item.animate({ direction: value });
    return direction;
}

animateObject($("#item"), 'left', 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function that return object what you want

```
 $("#item").animate(function(dir,val){
                        var obj={};
                        obj[dir] = val;
                        return obj;
                   }(get_direction(1,2), 1000));
```

also you can use srting and json parse like this

```
$("#item").animate(JSON.parse('{"'+get_direction(1,2)+'":"'+1000+'"}'));
```